# Python paramiko executing sudo

Tags: python, linux, paramiko

I am using paramiko `put` method to send file from local to remote server.
However, I am having problem executing `sudo su - user` command to view the file from remote. I also tried changing the permission from local but the file permission stays intact when transferred.

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(<Host>, username=<User Name>, password=<Password)

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put(<Source>, <Destination>)
sftp.close()
```

Is there a way to execute `sudo su - user` command using paramkio so the transferred files can be read from remote?

Thank you!

Comment: `ssh.exec_command(command)` is the way of execute a command

Comment: @RajarshiDas ... correct,  however that runs it in its own shell so that any changes would not be used by the call to `open_ssh`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no you cannot do this... however you can sort of work around it, by using sudo to move the file after its uploaded

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(<Host>, username=<User Name>, password=<Password)

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put(<Source>, destination_i_CAN_write_to)
sftp.close()

#now move the file to the sudo required area!
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo -S -p '' mv /uploaded/path/to/file.txt /restricted/sudo/path/file.txt",**kwargs)
stdin.write(SUDO_PASSWORD + "\n")
stdin.flush()
```

the `-S` flag on `sudu` tells it to expect the password to come from stdin

the `-p ''` flag tells sudo to use `''` or the empty string as the prompt for the password

you **cannot** simply use `sudo su - username` in an `exec_command` before the call to `open_ssh`, because each call to `exec_command` runs in its own subshell, as such the changes will not propagate back to the main session

Comment: thanks so much. Do you know if there is a way to change permission and preserve it when using paramiko?

Comment: there is not ... I guess you could mess with your system permissions to use softlinks into the protected area or simply granting permissions to the user you are logged in with

Comment: I am trying to use same code, but instead of mv I am using cp command. In my case neither of the commands are working as when I do ssh.exec_command('ls -l destination_folder), I don't see file being copied. I also tried checking by manually connection from ssh to remote server but I still can't see file being copied. What could be the reason? Is there any specific format to provide the password?
Right now I am strong password as a string variable.

Comment: Also, when I manually use this command in the remote location : sudo -S -p " " cp /sourcefile /destination_location", and when I provide password on prompt, I can see file being copied. But the same is not working for me using paramiko.